# How to upload .mp4 video on facebook using graph api in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am using Graph API to upload video on facebook. I am able to upload .wmv format video but not .mp4. My code is as below

```
strVidUrl=@"http://myshow.com.au/Videos/mp4s/20111216044530271247467.mp4";
    //strVidUrl=@"http://www.myshow.com.au/Videos/BossAlarm.wmv";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strVidUrl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   data, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/mp4", @"contentType",
                                   [dicVideoDetails valueForKey:@"fld_display_name"], @"title",
                                   [dicVideoDetails valueForKey:@"fld_video_description"], @"description",
                                   nil];
```

if I use .wmv then code is below and it is running.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myshow.com.au/Videos/BossAlarm.wmv"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               data, @"video.mov",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                               @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                                   nil];
```

Result is comming same in both cases but .mp4 video is not showing on facebook. while .wmv is showing there.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be due to the missmatch of  codecs and compression rates of your source video and fb's recomented video format

Comment: but .mp4 is suported format by facebook. check this link: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=218673814818907

Comment: mp4 is supported but its codec may different. Just manually upload the  video file and note what happens

Comment: My coversion code is 
exec(FFLV_PATH."ffmpeg -i '".$sourcePath."' -sameq -ar 22050 '".$outputPath."'");

do I need to add any codec here

is there any issue

Comment: to check the compatibility of your video
just download(i think the videofile is in a server) and upload it manually to fb. Or share that link manually. Then see if the video is working

Answer (score 0):

Check the following Links

- [Upload Video on facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/)
- [demo](http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/VideoUploadTest.zip)

Regards,
Let me know in case of queries.